# Admin Generator: can't have filters on primary keys(from the many-to-many tables) in the intermediate table

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my Symfony's admin Generator,I have a "many-to-many" relation b/w "Monitor" and "Server". In the result table "Benchmark" i can't see filters for servers and monitors! 
Is this Normal? and is there any solution to add this filters!

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, a filter is not a select tool. Just helps you to find what you may search by a description. If you know the primary key you can directly access to the element, so is senseless to filter by primary key.

If you need to add this fields you can add them in your BenchmarkForm class in /lib/form/ folder in your project

Comment: a benchmark object is composed by a monitor and a server (+ other infos), what i want is that in the benchmark list i can filter benchmarks by monitors or by servers! you see?

Comment: try to add this fields to the form. Other solution could be to order the list by server ID, so you'll have together all the same server monitors.

Comment: i already added them, and they appear in the "new" benchmark's interface, but still no filter!

Comment: did you added in the list and filter sections on its generator.yml file?

Comment: in filter when i whrite display: [monitor,server] it says that Widget "monitor" does not exist

Comment: you must asign a widget for each field in the filter form. You can do that adding in the form configuration: $this->setWidget('fieldname',new sfWhateverWidget);

Comment: public function configure()
  {
      parent::configure();
      unset ($this['created_at'], $this['updated_at']);
      
  $this->widgetSchema['monitor_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Monitor'));
  $this->widgetSchema['server_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Server'));

  $this->validatorSchema['monitor_id'] = new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Monitor'));
  $this->validatorSchema['server_id'] = new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Server'));
  }

Comment: sorry, now it appears, but it doesn't work, nothing happens! any idea?

Comment: don't you think i have to override the buildQuery() function?

Comment: i have no idea what that buildQuery() function is. :S but if its the function that makes the query to the database to show only the filtered results, i don't know if override, but probably you'll need to modify the function